# JSF - PrimeFaces , How to get the value of a booleanCheckbox / booleanButton in a list

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a jsf page that I can't update the value of some checkboxes in a list of `userDamain` objects, in fact this is a part of my jsf page :

```
    <h:outputText value="USER's rights list: "></h:outputText>
    <p:dataTable id="userss" var="userr" value="#{userMB.userListe}">

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="FirstName" /></f:facet>                     
            <h:outputText value="#{userr.firstName}"  />                    
    </p:column>


    <p:column>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">  
                <h:outputText value="Basic Usage: " />  
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userr.deletee}" immediate="true" actionListener="#{userr.deletee}"  />      
            </h:panelGrid> 

            <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />  
            <p:dialog header="Selected Values" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" widgetVar="dlg">  
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="display">  
                    <h:outputText value="Value 1: #{userr.deletee}" />  
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </p:dialog>      


    </p:column>
```

when I click on the boolean button 'Submit', the value of the `userr.deletee` is always false ( the default value ) and it's not updated anyway, I tried to use the Listner and actionListener in the booleanButton but it doesn't work, I also tried the postValidate event, so if someone has any idea of that, I would be graceful.

this is a part of my managed bean:

```
private List<UserDomain> userListe ;


    public List<UserDomain> getUserListe() {
        return this.userListe;
    }

    public void loadUserListe(){
        this.userListe = new ArrayList<UserDomain>();
        this.userListe.addAll(getUserServicee().getAll());
    }


    public void setUserListe(List<UserDomain> userListe) {
        this.userListe = userListe;
    }
```

a part of the userDomain bean:

```
...
public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
@Transient
    private boolean deletee;

    public boolean isDeletee() {
        return deletee;
    }

    public void setDeletee(boolean deletee) {
        this.deletee = deletee;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution which seems logic to me, I added to my checkbox an ajax behavior to execute a method and an attribute which called in this method to get the whole `userDomain` object, so on I can get the `user.deletee` value, here is a part of the code I m talking about:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">  
                    <h:outputText value="Delete Right: " />  

                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userr.deletee}">  
                        <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{userMB.saveUserRights}" />
                        <f:attribute name="user" value="#{userr}" />
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox> 

                </h:panelGrid>
```

I hope this will be helpful for you